# Monitor data usage on Windows?

Tags: windows

How can I monitor the amount of data usage, i.e. the total amount of data transfered on the network? I want to know how much data would I use if I was connected on mobile LTE network.

The standard Performance Monitor tool seems to monitor only the current state. I want to see the total amount over past days.

Solution for Windows XP/10.

Comment: I have been using **DU Meter** for ages. But it is not a free product. You can look for alternatives to it at: https://alternativeto.net/software/dumeter/

Comment: Please explain why you need a single solution that works on these two operating systems which are separated by 15 years. Your question may be closed as too broad of you simply want two answers from one question.

Comment: I dont see any point in duplicating this into two questions for two systems, when some of the solutions can be for both.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10: Settings → Network & Internet → Data Usage.

Comment: That can be valid for Windows 10 but not for XP. Could you please address that too?