# How to access data usage for custom range (on already existing data usage on Windows 10)?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, windows-registry, network-monitoring

I have data usage logged on my Windows 10 laptop at `Windows Settings → Network & Internet → Data Usage`.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is instead of getting data usage for the last 30 days, I want to get data usage for custom time range `e.g. from 15-Mar to 3-April`. Other important thing, I don't want to use a solution that neglects the preexisting data usage log. I've tried many applications that neglects any before-installation logged data usage.

Something like this is possible on Android by application called [Glasswire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glasswire.android&hl=en) which reads and calculates data usage based on already preexisting data usage log provided by Android system.

I've tried the [Windows version](https://www.glasswire.com/download/) of Glasswire, unfortunately it seems to be depending on monitoring the network activity from the time Glasswire was installed (like many apps I have tried) and any previous data usage isn't added to calculations, unlike its android version which reads the preexisting data usage log.

One of the solutions I think about is to access the place where detailed temporal information about internet data usage is stored (may be a system file, or a Registry entry). I don't know how can I find this if someone can help.

My question is different from this one — [Monitor data usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1446007/monitor-data-usage-on-windows) — which asks about anyway of monitoring total amount of data usage specifying the date and preexisting data usage.

Comment: Windows may not be able to display that information, but your router could. If you log on to the admin page of your router, isn't there a counter or graph to indicate how much data has been used over a specified period? Some router OEMs include that functionality in the router firmware, others rely on third-party add-ons or apps to do that (remember that most routers use one version of Linux or another for their firmware, so it's easy to create a fork or custom version of the factory firmware to add functionalities). What's the brand and model of your router?

Answer (score 1):

I found [NetworkUsageView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_usage_view.html) utility from NirSoft that does exactly this. It displays the information that Windows already stores in the `SRUDB.dat` file inside the Windows directory, so no third party monitoring needed. Every log item is displayed on a line (the logs are per application and they are kept sometimes hourly, sometimes every five minutes; I don't know what determines the frequency), but it is easy to get the usage for a custom time range: just select all the items in the desired range, and the status bar shows the total downloads and uploads.

One caveat: I think some of the records that Windows keeps are duplicated. E.g. under most data usage entries for my browser, there was another entry, without an app name and with an App ID of 1, that had almost the same upload and download numbers (slightly higher). Presumably Windows is aware of these and avoids double counting them, but NetworkUsageView naively showed their sum when both entries were selected. I didn't look into this much, as what I wanted to do was getting usages per program anyway so this wasn't a problem; but if my guess is right and these rows are duplicates that shouldn't be counted, it should be possible to filter out those rows and then get the accurate sum for all programs.